# Prevent Black Studio TinyMCE from adding <p> tags when switching from Visual to HTML mode

Tags: tinymce, wp-autop

I'm having a really annoying problem with [Black Studio TinyMCE Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/black-studio-tinymce-widget/) in Wordpress, wherein the plugin always adds paragraph `p` tags around any text, image, link, object when switching from Visual editing mode to HTML mode within the widget.

The switch is often needed to refine some details in the code, but then most formatting is corrupted by these unwanted `p` tags.

Has anyone had this experience and/or has a solution?

Answer (score 0):

[This question has been answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20464028/how-to-remove-unwanted-p-tags-from-wordpress-editor-tinymce)

You need to "add a simple filter function" to functions.php file for the theme via regex.

Answer (score 0):

I have when editing articles sometimes appear `p` tags, and I remove them with the help of Shift + Enter